# Pure CSS drop down menu has z-index issue when introducing a jQuery carousel beneath it

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu, z-index

I have a pure CSS drop down navigation menu that works just fine on its own, but when I introduce the Elixon Theatre 2.5 (a 3D-ish jQuery image carousel purchased from http://www.webdevelopers.eu) beneath the navigational menu, I get a `z-index` type of issue. The two drop down menus (classes and staff) disappear as soon as I hover the mouse over the first drop down `<li>` element that overlaps with the carousel. I tried making the `z-index` of the parent `<ul>` higher than that of the carousel, but it didn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

The page can be found here: [www.washmoarts.com/gallery.html](http://www.washmoarts.com/gallery.html)

Here's the CSS for the nav menu:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #666;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset,
                0px -3px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1100;
}
ul#nav {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1001;
}
ul#nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 200%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
ul#nav ul {
    background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.8);
    font-size: .85em;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    left: -99999px;
    opacity: 0; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
}
ul#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    height: 24px;
}
ul#nav li:hover a {
    color: #8fc73e;
}
ul#nav li:hover ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0 20px;
    min-width: 70px;
}
ul#nav li:hover ul {
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
ul#nav li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #457895;
    height: 24px;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="grid_12" id="navbar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a id="nav-home" href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-classes" href="javascript:void(0);">classes</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="classes/art.html">art</a></li>
                <li><a href="classes/dance.html">dance</a></li>
                <li><a href="classes/pilates.html">pilates</a></li>
                <li><a href="classes/theatre.html">theatre</a></li>
                <li><a href="classes/tumbling.html">tumbling</a></li>
                <li><a href="classes/voice.html">voice</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a id="nav-staff" href="javascript:void(0);">staff</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="staff/AdrienneBranson.html">Adrienne Branson (dance/pilates)</a></li> 
                <li><a href="staff/CharissaCoyle.html">Charissa Coyle (art)</a></li>
                <li><a href="staff/ChristiMitchell.html">Christi Mitchell (theatre)</a></li>
                <li><a href="staff/KendraMuir.html">Kendra Muir (voice)</a></li>
                <li><a href="staff/KarlaVeltrop.html">Karla Veltrop (tumbling)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a id="nav-calendar" href="calendar.html">calendar</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-events" href="events.html">events</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-gallery" href="javascript:void(0);">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-register" href="media/RegistrationForm.pdf" target="_blank">register</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-contact" href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
.
.
.

<div id="myGallery" style="visibility: hidden; text-align: center; margin: auto; width: 80%; height: 300px;">
    <a href="images/gallery-01-hires.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/gallery-01-lowres.jpg" style="height: 1px;"/></a>
    <a href="images/gallery-02-hires.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/gallery-02-lowres.jpg" style="height: 1px;"/></a>
    <a href="images/gallery-03-hires.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/gallery-03-lowres.jpg" style="height: 1px;"/></a>
    <a href="images/gallery-04-hires.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/gallery-04-lowres.jpg" style="height: 1px;"/></a>
    <a href="images/gallery-05-hires.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/gallery-05-lowres.jpg" style="height: 1px;"/></a>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#myGallery").theatre({
            /* other options here */

            controls: "horizontal",
            speed: 2000,
            still: 2000,
            selector: "img",
            effect: "3d"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I can't post the jQuery carousel code because it's copyrighted. I hope someone can still help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
#myGallery { z-index: -100; }
```

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't work, unfortunately. I'm thinking that the z-indexes of the child elements of #myGallery are interfering with everything else maybe.

Comment: Oh wow! Huge rookie mistake on my part! When I had made the change you suggested I applied it to an offline copy of the site I use for testing, but when I checked to see if it had worked or not I looked at the live site. I'm sorry to have wasted your time, everyone.

Comment: Just glad you got it all figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to put your navigation and gallery inside a common div. style each with position:relative, then define a z-index for the nav and gallery.

Comment: You're correct. In fact, that's what I'm already doing. I'm using the 960 Grid System as a container div around the whole thing. My problem was was a huge rookie mistake that I've now cleared up. Sorry for wasting your time, but thank you so much for the help!